# Adding a nested value as a field - MongDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

So I have a parent document with users, as well as an array that has users too. I want to add the DisplayName from the nested users array to the aggregation output. Any ideas?

Output I'm looking to achieve:

```
   [
    {
      "user": {
        "_id": "11",
        "Name": "Dave",
        "DocID": "1",
        "DocDisplyName": "ABC"
      },
    {
      "user": {
        "_id": "33",
        "Name": "Henry",
        "DocID": "1",
        "DocDisplyName": "ABC",
        "BranchDisplayName:"BranchA"
      }
    }
   ]
```

And so on.. So an array of all users and for users that belong to a branch, add the branch display Name to the output.

`// Doc 1`

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "DisplayName": "ABC",
  "Users": [
    { "_id": "11", "Name": "Dave" },
    { "_id": "22", "Name": "Steve" }
  ],
  "Branches": [
    {
      "_id": "111",
      "DisplayName": "BranchA",
      "Users": [
        { "_id": "33", "Name": "Henry" },
        { "_id": "44", "Name": "Josh" },
      ],
    },
    {
        "_id": "222",
        "DisplayName": "BranchB",
        "Users": [
          { "_id": "55", "Name": "Mark" },
          { "_id": "66", "Name": "Anton" },
        ],
      }
  ]
}
```

``Doc 2

```
    {
    "_id": "2",
    "DisplayName": "DEF",
    "Users": [
      { "_id": "77", "Name": "Josh" },
      { "_id": "88", "Name": "Steve" }
    ],
    "Branches": [
      {
        "_id": "333",
        "DisplayName": "BranchA",
        "Users": [
          { "_id": "99", "Name": "Henry" },
          { "_id": "10", "Name": "Josh" },
        ],
      },
      {
          "_id": "444",
          "DisplayName": "BranchB",
          "Users": [
            { "_id": "112", "Name": "Susan" },
            { "_id": "112", "Name": "Mary" },
          ],
        }
    ]
  }
```

```
Collection.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        branchUsers: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$Branches.Users",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        user: {
          $concatArrays: ["$branchUsers", "$Users"],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "user.DocID": "$_id","user.DocDisaplyName": "$DisplayName"
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$user",
    },
   
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user: 1,
      },
    }
  ])


Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution.

```
  {
            $addFields: {
                "branchUsers.BranchDisplayName": {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            first: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [ "$Branches", 0 ]
                            }
                        },
                        in: "$$first.DisplayName"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

This creates the field only for the users that belong to the branch